# SciPy periodogram for finite-length signal

Tags: signals, spectrum

I input a finite-length signal to the periodogram function and get the power spectrum density. However, since the signal has a finite length, the power spectrum density I get has a sinc-like lobes. Is there any implantation in SciPy, which can be used to de-couple the sinc-like lobes so that I can get the power spectrum density for the infinite version of the finite-length signal?